# Add a code for tables to markdown

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown

Sometimes, I would like to show a table in a post—for example, when I have a question about SQL.

Here is an idea: create the ability to make tables, so we can specify name and fields. For example:

```
Table{Name:Table1,field1:id values(1,2,3,4), field2:name values(Ali, Ana, Sophia, James, Arnold)}
```

And the result is shown like a table view.

Comment: Why can't you do an ASCII-art table using inline-code or a code-block? For those few cases I needed such, that worked great. BTW: There are stack-snippets now, if you really need them.

Comment: See [Is there any markdown to create tables?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: @Deduplicator To be noted, the Stack Snippets are only running on Meta right now.

Comment: @animuson with CommonMark now a thing, is this something that could potentially change in the future?

Comment: @Joe Possibly. CommonMark only adds the ability to use free-form `<table>` and related HTML in the post and doesn't actually provide any specification for generating tables. I'd say it's unlikely. Personally, I would never implement a system that allowed users to input HTML tables and render them. Too much parsing to try and make sure it's valid, but without it you run the risk of users destroying the page. I think that was a horrible addition to the CommonMark specification.

Comment: @animuson it is a strange one, I can't help but think that was pushed by Vicent Marti for GitHub use. Pure speculation of course. Thanks for clearing that up though.

Comment: Marking this [status-declined] seems a bit pre-mature. This is something that we should be able to discuss on the Stack Overflow Meta, with specific application to Stack Overflow. It hasn't already been discussed here, and maybe there's some whiz here who can [help the poor Stack Exchange developers figure out how to use inline tables without breaking their entire site layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228464/153008).

Comment: I second this. However I think a simple markdown like [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) is enough. And I think GitHub Flavored Markdown is also more appropriate for a programming site like SO

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250157/could-stack-overflow-support-github-flavored-markdown?rq=1