# Docs markdown and code block language hints

Tags: feature-request, documentation, markdown

I'm continually seeing [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/91367) in Docs where people use the triple `` ` `` and a language declaration to wrap their code

````
```php <?php some code here ?> ```
````

It's quite annoying because, when you wrap your code blocks in it, it actually has the **opposite effect** in that it disables syntax highlighting

Wrapped as described

[image: No Syntax highlighting]

Indented without wrapping

[image: Syntax highlighting]

As you can see, the system seems to figure it out pretty readily. Sadly, most people don't seem to know that in Docs, you can hint a language using this before your code block

```
<!-- language: sql -->
```

Can something be done to catch this and alert the user not to wrap code blocks like this? Or perhaps make it more obvious how to hint what type of code a block is?

Comment: Submissions that use formatting codes appropriate for some other site might be a result of user experience with other Markdown flavors... but it might also indicate copy+paste of Markdown from elsewhere.  Such cases should be carefully inspected for plagiarism.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260541/248058

Answer (score 6):

We should block the use of the backtick wrapper ```` ``` ```` altogether.

It doesn't make sense to use on SO, nor on docs.

Besides, the `<!-- language: lang-lng -->` tag works on both sites.

Comment: -1 - the HTML comment syntax is neither obvious, nor easy to remember, and as such is one of the more user-unfriendly parts of the authoring experience.

Comment: @SeanVieira yeah, who knew that triple backticks was easy to remember and user friendly?

Comment: They are not any more intuitive than the 4 space indentation, but once introduced to the <code>```tag</code> syntax I doubt many people forget it.  I've been on SO since right after the beta and I *still* have to look up the comment syntax.  Just one data point, but there it is :-)

Answer (score 5):

How about we, oh I don't know, get Docs to actually [*use the hints in this Markdown* the way CommonMark suggests](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.26/#fenced-code-blocks)? If there's a broken feature in the Docs implementation (of supporting fenced codeblocks, which was explicitly included where [it doesn't yet work on SE proper](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks)), the correct thing to do is finish implementing the feature the right way. Not take it out because the unfinished version isn't as useful yet.

Comment: Here's the funny thing about this: *it actually works that way now*. It functionally works exactly like a `<code>` block. The issue here is that blocks syntax highlighting (which is not covered by CM that I can see). But you're right. There's inconstancy here.

Comment: @Machavity: Right, the code block is implemented, but the highlighting isn't, nor the recommended use of the info text as a language hint.