# Can we use ``` instead of 4 blank spaces for code markdown?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, user-experience

It's really annoying having to manually indent code after copy/pasting when it goes wrong. It'd be easier just to type:

```

my code here

```

And no indentation. Thanks!

Comment: Or, select the code block and then `Ctrl + k` to auto indent... (or the `{}` button on the toolbar).

Comment: See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250157/3933332

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the <kbd>{}</kbd> button in the toolbar to indent selected code (or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> as [@Oded mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336243/can-we-use-instead-of-4-blank-spaces-for-code-markdown/336244#comment404034_336243)). As long as the selected code contains a non-indented line, it will insert four spaces in front of each line.