# Is Stack Overflow Markdown based on GitHub Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

Does Stack Overflow use the same Markdown flavor as GitHub? Are the differences documented somewhere?

Comment: Related: [Could Stack Overflow support GitHub flavored markdown?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250157/3853934)

Answer (score 5):

No, Stack Overflow uses [Common Mark specification](http://commonmark.org/) of Markdown.

It's not the same as GitHub Markdown, because for example GitHub Markdown allows tables, but Common Mark doesn't.

See [Time to fork Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230014/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are you sure it is already on CommonMark? Given [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258587/158100)?

Comment: Stack Overflow predates Common Mark, and they have not fully resolved the differences last I heard.